# A proof that Compact sets are not open

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness

I've come across the theorem that says all Compact sets are closed, and I'd like to prove on my own that compact sets are NOT open.

(Originally I intended to prove that compact sets are closed but later realized that a set can be both open and closed, so a set that is not open does not determine whether it's closed or not).

What I'm about to write isn't a rigorously written proof, it's just my thought process. My argument considers the metric space $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $A$ is compact and, by contradiction, is open. Then for any element in it, say $x$, there is a neighborhood containing it with radius $r_x > 0$, and it's easy to prove that $\displaystyle A \subseteq \bigcup_{x \in A}N_{r_x}(x)$.

Now, since A is compact, there exists $x_1,\dots, x_n$ such that $\displaystyle A \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}N_{r_{x_i}}(x)$.

Here I started thinking as follows (this is where I'm skeptical): Let $x_1 < x_2 <\dots< x_n$ and for each $x_i$, choose $0 < r_i < r_{x_i}$ for which $N_{r_i}(x_i) \cap N_{r_j}(x_j) = \phi$ where $i < j$ and $x_j - r_j > x_i + r_i$. It's possible by using the Denseness Property of the reals to find $r_j$ and $r_i$, and if $0 < r_i < r_{x_i}$ then clearly $N_{r_i}(x_i) \subset A$.

This would imply that there is $y$ in A that isn't in any of these neightborhoods, so A cannot be a subset of their unions, which contradicts A being compact (I can add more detail here to show why there is such a $y$. If, WLOG, $x_2 < y < x_3$ but no point exists in this interval in A, then $x_2$ is not an interior point so A is not open which is a contradiction).

Is this correct? Am I missing something? Is there something I'm misunderstanding about the definition of compactness?

Thank you for any comment, it's highly valuable.

Comment: Compact sets *can* be open. An isolated point in a topological space forms a singleton set that is both compact (since it's finite) and open (since it's isolated).

Comment: Your argument relies on the existence of a metric, which is fine, but it means the statement should be narrower. Also considering that you write $x_1 < x_2 < \cdots $ and $x_j - r_j$, where $r_j$ would be a real number, is your argument intended specifically for $\mathbb{R}$ with the metric topology?

Comment: I'm sorry that I didnt include it, but yeah my argument only considers the metric space $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Then edit your post and put whole thing w.r.to euclidean metric on $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: @Qwen_Marbell Unfortunately, I believe that your reasoning is still incorrect. A subset is compact if an arbitrary open cover has a finite subcover. This does not mean that the finite subcover can be changed arbitrarily -- there is no contradiction with $N_{r_i}(x_i)$ not covering $A$.

Comment: @legionwhale I see. So I cannot simply argue that I can decrease the radius even if the neighborhood still remains a subset of $A$, is that correct?

Comment: @Qwen_Marbell Yes. I can suggest an approach that may work with similar reasoning, although I'm not sure it will so it may not be worth your time. Show that proper open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are not complete. Assume your compact set is open, and now consider a Cauchy sequence that does not converge in the set. You may be able to show that an appropriately defined open cover has no finite subcover. I am not sure if this is guaranteed to work though. Just a thought. For metric spaces in general, it is known that compact implies closed, and is also equivalent to complete and totally bounded.